# How to use group_concat with groupBy function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to concatenate my `users.id` using groupBy function. But it throws me an error. `Undefined property: stdClass::$id`. I think I didn't missed something because I already import `use DB;` at the top of my file.

Here how I do it in **SQL**

```
SELECT D.department_name, GROUP_CONCAT(U.id) user_id FROM users U
INNER JOIN departments D ON D.id = U.department_id group by D.department_name;
```

Laravel Eloquent:

```
$departmentRecipient = DB::table('users')->select('departments.department_name', DB::raw('group_concat(users.id)'))
    ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'users.department_id')
    ->groupBy('departments.department_name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: That error is probably coming from another line. Can you check the error and see which line it's coming from?

Comment: @aynber It already working I just added `users.id`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access the group_contact property, you need to name it. Otherwise, MySQL will name the column with the function name.

```
DB::raw('group_concat(users.id) AS id')
```